# Max min of functionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I have an interesting question which I believe was probably already studied, but I could not find anything. Let $n, m \geq 1$ be fixed. Suppose that $|| \cdot ||$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m$ are functionals of norm at least $1$ (in the dual norm of $|| \cdot ||$). I am asking for lower or upper bounds for
$$\max_{||x||=1} \min_{1 \leq i \leq m} |f_i(x)|.$$

In the case of $|| \cdot ||$ being an Euclidean norm I believe that I have obtained the lower bound of $\frac{1}{(n-1)m}$ (if I am not wrong of course). For the general norm, by a simple application of John's Ellipsoid theorem one can obtain a lower bound of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)m}$.

I am interested in any information concerning this problem, both in some special norm (like Euclidean) or in the general case.

Comment: I do not understand your claimed lower bound.  For fixed $m$ it should be increasing in $n$; moreover, it is clearly wrong for $n=1$.

Comment: Yeah, it works for $n>1$. I do not know however, why for fixed $m$ it should be increasing in $n$. I am sorry if this is a silly question but could you elaborate a little bit more?